# How solve this probability problem?

Tags: probability

We have $n$ beds labeled as $B_1, B_2,.., B_n$ and we have $n$ person labeled as $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$. We assign each bed to one person. What is the probability of which person and bed subscripts don't equal? For instance, we can't assign $B_1$ to $P_1$.

If $n=2$, the solution is $1\over 2$

If $n=3$, the solution is $1\over 3$

If $n=4$, the solution is $3\over 8$

I just wrote all possibilities for $n=2,3,4$.

What about $n$ bed and people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a classic derangement problem. Check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)